# Algorithm for a Program which can convert Roman to Decimal

Tags: algorithm

I need some help regarding algorithm, I have attached a problem in it which says that i have to develop an algorithm for a program which can convert Roman to Decimal.

I don't know how to do it, would prefer a complete algorithm but any help is appreciated.
It is an algorithm not a program!

[image]

Comment: It would help if you said which programming language you are supposed to do this in

Comment: Its in C. But its algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to traverse the roman numeral string from end to start. For each character, add the corresponding number to the result. For some special
cases, such as ‘I’, ‘X’, ‘C’, check if the result is greater than the corresponding number. If yes, we need to subtract the number
from the result. If no, we need to add the number to the result.

```
res = 0
for each character c backwards:
  if c =='I' 
    res += res + (res >= 5 ? -1 : 1)
  else if c=='V' 
    res += res + 5
  else if c=='X' 
    res += 10 * (res >= 50 ? -1 : 1)
  else if c=='L' 
    res += 50;
  else if c == 'C' 
    res += 100 * (res >= 500 ? -1 : 1)
  else if c== 'D' 
    res += 500
  else if c=='M' 
    res += 1000
return res
```

For example: MMDCCCXCIX

= 0 + MMDCCCXCIX

= 10 + MMDCCCXCI

= 9 + MMDCCCXC (as 10 > 5)

= 109 + MMDCCCX

= 99 + MMDCCC (as 109 > 50)

= 199 + MMDCC

= 299 + MMDC

= 399 + MMD

= 899 + MM

= 1899 + M

= 2899

Comment: Thanks. But please tell me the abbreviations of variables.

Comment: @HaXnainNoOrani res is the result and c is the current character of the roman number that we iterate on.

Comment: You are a life saver bro.

Comment: Can I use index =0?

Comment: @HaXnainNoOrani I guess you are new in this site. If you want to say thank you, then just vote up. No need to say thank you. Then there would be a lot of useless comments just saying thanks

Comment: What if res>=5 becomes false. It will add 1 or something??

Comment: If it is true it adds -1, if it is false it adds 1. I'm starting feel like I make your homework for you. You really need to be able to figure out these things by yourself.